# Exception throw when creating Path instance

Tags: java, file, exception, java.nio.file

I am trying to create an instance of Path's class at a specific folder by using environment variable. Here is my code:

```
Path pathName = Paths.get(System.getenv("USER") + "/AGENDA");
System.out.println(chemin);
    if(Files.exists(pathName)) {
      System.out.println("Directory already exists!");
    }
    else 
    {
        try {
            Files.createDirectories(pathName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Directory newly created!");
    }
```

When I run,the console shows:

```
/feujio/AGENDA
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /feujio
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:384)
at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674)
at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:781)
at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:767)
at File.FilePaths.createPath(FilePaths.java:44)
at File.FilePaths.main(FilePaths.java:63)

Directory newly created!
```

When I do not use an environment variable, it works. I can't explain this behavior.

Comment: So the directory should probably start with a slash, i.e. `/my-username/AGENDA`?

Comment: It shows the same issue. I wrote: `Path pathName = Paths.get("/" + System.getenv("USER") + "/AGENDA");`

Comment: [`AccessDeniedException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/AccessDeniedException.html) suggests that you have a problem with file permissions for the user running the Java process.

Comment: When you do not use the environment variable, what path is used for the directory? My suspicion is that you wanted to put that in the user's home directory, i.e. `home/feujio/AGENDA` not `/feujio/AGENDA`.

Comment: When I do not use environment variable, I set a path relatively to my my eclipse-workspace folder. I mean if I set `pathName = Paths.gets("../../AGENDA")`, the directories will be created inside my eclipse-workspace folder. And I do `pathName = Paths.get("../../../AGENDA")` then the directory is created at the folder I wanted. This solution does not satisfy me as I want it to work on other operating system. Here I'm using a Linux OS.

Comment: So, you have the permissions to create a directory inside your eclipse-workspace folder, but you don’t have the permission to create a new folder in the root directory. What’s so hard to understand about that? Why do you assume that this could work at all? Perhaps, you actually meant `System.getenv("HOME")` to denote the user’s home directory, however, if the code is supposed to run on other operating systems as well, you should not mess around with system specific environment variables at all. Use `System.getProperty("user.home")` to get the user’s home directory in a portable way.

Answer (score 0):

Javadoc of [`Files.createDirectory()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectory-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-):

> Creates a new directory. The check for the existence of the file and the creation of the directory if it does not exist are a single operation that is atomic with respect to all other filesystem activities that might affect the directory. **The `createDirectories` method should be used where it is required to create all nonexistent parent directories first.**
>
> [...]
>
> Throws `IOException` if an I/O error occurs or **the parent directory does not exist**

[`NoSuchFileException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/NoSuchFileException.html) is an `IOException`.

Which means that `my-username` is not an existing directory in the **current directory**, whatever the current directory is.

Comment: By `my-username` I mean the name of the current session opened on my computer. The `createDirectories ` shows the same issue: `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException : my-userName`

Comment: @FEUJIOMarieTherese `createDirectories` (plural) is not supposed to throw that particular error. Are you sure you're running updated code? The stack trace would show for sure. Also, what is the current directory? Edit your question to show updated code, full stack trace, and add code to show what current directory is, e.g. by getting *absolute path* of `pathName`.

Comment: I just replaced the `createDirectory()` method by the `createDirectories()` method. Ok I edit my question